# How to hide a chrome extension side panel when the URL changes

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to use the Chrome Extension Side Panel in an extension to let the user select a photo and information from the main page when they click on the action button in the toolbar.

I can get the side panel to appear when they click the action button, but the problem is that it remains there as we change URLs and change tabs.

Ive tried hooking into the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {` event with this:

```
        chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
            tabId,
            enabled: false
        });
```

But this appears to DISABLE the entire side panel and won't let it open up again.  There doesn't appear to simply be a "close side panel" option for chrome extensions.

Does anyone know how to code this so that it will open the side panel when they click on the action item and if they change URLs or click on a different tab, close the side panel?  I know I could use a content script to create a div and inject it on the page but then it wont have that "side panel" feel (unless I wrap the entire page in a div and use CSS to make a pseudo side panel, which is a bad idea).

Comment: Simply call `close()` inside the side panel script.